# Is there any function to use to see the new updated array state using React Js Hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have question pertaining to use of Effect Hook, Right now I have module when I click the button it will automatically add 5 new array so each row has onChange this is probably working now. However when I console log the state still no effect but in my view has already effect.

**Problem: Why my state still 5 but my rows on my table already 10..**

**Here is the sample output:**

[image: sample output]

As you can see I have already 10 because I already add new rows but in default 5 rows only.
but when I console it logs inside of my onchange handler the state has only 5, there is no reflection happen when I console logs the state.

Based on my research I need to use React Hook Effects, But how to do it in Hooks Effect? I will show you guys my sample code that I created.

Here is the default 5 default state:

```
    const [data, setData] = useState([{
      key: "1",
      customer: <select className="form-control" name="customer" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,0)} >
                    <option  key="0" disabled selected>Select Customer</option>
                    <option  key="1">LEXI INC / joseph</option>
                    <option  key="1">LEXI INC / james</option>
                    <option  key="1">LEXI INC / charlie</option>
                    <option  key="1">LEXI INC / pam</option>
                    <option  key="1">LEXI INC / regorio</option>
                </select>,
      bank: <select className="form-control" name="bank" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,0)}>
                <option  key="0" disabled selected>Select Bank</option>
                <option  key="1">BDO</option>
                <option  key="1">MAY BANK</option>
                <option  key="1">EAST WEST BANK</option>
                <option  key="1">UNION BANK</option>
                <option  key="1">BPI</option>
            </select>,
      branch: <input className="form-control" placeholder="Branch" name="branch"  onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,0)}/>,
      checkNo: <input type="number" className="form-control" name="checkNo" placeholder="Check No." onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,0)}/>,
      checkDate: <input type="date" name="checkDate" className="form-control" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,0)}/>,
      amount: <input
                name="amount"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Amount"
                onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,0)} 
              />,
      remarks: <select className="form-control" name="remarks" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,0)}>
                  <option  key="0" disabled selected>Select Remarks</option>
                  <option  key="1">Test</option>
              </select>,
      
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    customer: <select className="form-control" name="customer" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,1)}>
                  <option  key="0" disabled selected>Select Customer</option>
                  <option  key="1">LEXI INC / james</option>
                  <option  key="1">LEXI INC / charlie</option>
                  <option  key="1">LEXI INC / pam</option>
                  <option  key="1">LEXI INC / regorio</option>
              </select>,
    bank: <select className="form-control" name="bank" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,1)}>
              <option  key="0" disabled selected>Select Bank</option>
              <option  key="1">BDO</option>
              <option  key="1">MAY BANK</option>
              <option  key="1">EAST WEST BANK</option>
              <option  key="1">UNION BANK</option>
              <option  key="1">BPI</option>
          </select>,
    branch: <input className="form-control" placeholder="Branch" name="branch" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,1)}/>,
    checkNo: <input type="number" className="form-control" name="checkNo" placeholder="Check No." onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,1)}/>,
    checkDate: <input type="date" name="checkDate" className="form-control" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,1)}/>,
    amount: <input
              name="amount"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Amount"
              onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,1)} 
            />,
    remarks: <select className="form-control" name="remarks" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,1)}>
                <option  key="0" disabled selected>Select Remarks</option>
                <option  key="1">Test</option>
            </select>,
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    customer: <select className="form-control" name="customer" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,2)}>
                  <option  key="0" disabled selected>Select Customer</option>
                  <option  key="1">LEXI INC / james</option>
                  <option  key="1">LEXI INC / charlie</option>
                  <option  key="1">LEXI INC / pam</option>
                  <option  key="1">LEXI INC / regorio</option>
              </select>,
    bank: <select className="form-control" name="bank" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,2)}>
              <option  key="0" disabled selected>Select Bank</option>
              <option  key="1">BDO</option>
              <option  key="1">MAY BANK</option>
              <option  key="1">EAST WEST BANK</option>
              <option  key="1">UNION BANK</option>
              <option  key="1">BPI</option>
          </select>,
    branch: <input className="form-control" placeholder="Branch" name="branch" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,2)}/>,
    checkNo: <input type="number" className="form-control" name="checkNo" placeholder="Check No." onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,2)}/>,
    checkDate: <input type="date" name="checkDate" className="form-control" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,2)}/>,
    amount: <input
              name="amount"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Amount"
              onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,2)} 
            />,
    remarks: <select className="form-control" name="remarks" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,2)}>
                <option  key="0" disabled selected>Select Remarks</option>
                <option  key="1">Test</option>
            </select>,
  },
  {
    key: "4",
    customer: <select className="form-control" name="customer" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,3)}>
                  <option  key="0" disabled selected>Select Customer</option>
                  <option  key="1">LEXI INC / james</option>
                  <option  key="1">LEXI INC / charlie</option>
                  <option  key="1">LEXI INC / pam</option>
                  <option  key="1">LEXI INC / regorio</option>
              </select>,
    bank: <select className="form-control" name="bank" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,3)}>
              <option  key="0" disabled selected>Select Bank</option>
              <option  key="1">BDO</option>
              <option  key="1">MAY BANK</option>
              <option  key="1">EAST WEST BANK</option>
              <option  key="1">UNION BANK</option>
              <option  key="1">BPI</option>
          </select>,
    branch: <input className="form-control" placeholder="Branch" name="branch" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,3)}/>,
    checkNo: <input type="number" className="form-control" name="checkNo" placeholder="Check No." onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,3)}/>,
    checkDate: <input type="date" name="checkDate" className="form-control" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,3)}/>,
    amount: <input
              name="amount"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Amount"
              onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,3)} 
            />,
    remarks: <select className="form-control" name="remarks" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,3)}>
                <option  key="0" disabled selected>Select Remarks</option>
                <option  key="1">Test</option>
            </select>,
  },
  {
    key: "5",
    customer: <select className="form-control" name="customer" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,4)}>
                  <option  key="0" disabled selected>Select Customer</option>
                  <option  key="1">LEXI INC / james</option>
                  <option  key="1">LEXI INC / charlie</option>
                  <option  key="1">LEXI INC / pam</option>
                  <option  key="1">LEXI INC / regorio</option>
              </select>,
    bank: <select className="form-control" name="bank" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,4)}>
              <option  key="0" disabled selected>Select Bank</option>
              <option  key="1">BDO</option>
              <option  key="1">MAY BANK</option>
              <option  key="1">EAST WEST BANK</option>
              <option  key="1">UNION BANK</option>
              <option  key="1">BPI</option>
          </select>,
    branch: <input className="form-control" placeholder="Branch" name="branch" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,4)}/>,
    checkNo: <input type="number" className="form-control" name="checkNo" placeholder="Check No." onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,4)}/>,
    checkDate: <input type="date" name="checkDate" className="form-control" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,4)}/>,
    amount: <input
              name="amount"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Amount"
              onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,4)} 
            />,
    remarks: <select className="form-control" name="remarks" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,4)}>
                <option  key="0" disabled selected>Select Remarks</option>
                <option  key="1">Test</option>
            </select>,
    }]) 

  

    const [list, setList] = useState(data);
```

Button Where when I click this it will add new 5 rows:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => addRows()}>Add Row</button>
```

AddRows Function:

```
const addRows = () => {

    //loop here the keys listed
    let initialKey = 0;

    const x = data.slice(-1);

    initialKey = parseInt(x[0]['key']);

    let newArr=[...Array(5)].map((_,i)=>{

        let val=i + 1 +initialKey;

         return {
            key: ""+val+"",
            customer: <select className="form-control" name="customer" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,val)}>
                            <option  key="0" disabled selected>Select Customer</option>
                            <option  key="6">LEXI INC / joseph</option>
                            <option  key="6">LEXI INC / james</option>
                            <option  key="6">LEXI INC / charlie</option>
                            <option  key="6">LEXI INC / pam</option>
                            <option  key="6">LEXI INC / regorio</option>
                        </select>,
            bank: <select className="form-control" name="bank" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,val)}>
                        <option  key="0" disabled selected>Select Bank</option>
                        <option  key="6">BDO</option>
                        <option  key="6">MAY BANK</option>
                        <option  key="6">EAST WEST BANK</option>
                        <option  key="6">UNION BANK</option>
                        <option  key="6">BPI</option>
                    </select>,
            branch: <input className="form-control" placeholder="Branch" name="branch" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,val)}/>,
            checkNo: <input type="number" className="form-control" name="checkNo" placeholder="Check No." onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,val)}/>,
            checkDate: <input type="date" name="checkDate" className="form-control" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,val)}/>,
            amount: <input
                        name="amount"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Amount"
                        onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,val)} 
                    />,
            remarks: <select className="form-control" name="remarks" onChange={(e,i) => handleInputChange(e,val)}>
                        <option  key="0" disabled selected>Select Remarks</option>
                        <option  key="6">Test</option>
                    </select>
         }
    });

    setData([...data,...newArr])

}
```

Here is function of OnChange

```
const handleInputChange = (e, i) => {

    console.log(i);

    const { name, value } = e.target;

    const list = [...data];

    console.log(list);
    
    const x = list[i];

    // const x = list[i][name] = value;

    console.log(x)
    
}
```

Output Onchange: Based on the logs the state is 5 only.

[image: Output onchange]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
useEffect(() => {

      setTimeout(()=>{
       setData(yourDataArray)
      }, 1000)

    }, [])
```

Comment: do I need to use SetTimeout I think this will give slowing on the browser??

Comment: Please explain more regarding on that. specially the data array and where to place on it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
// this will get run whenever `data` changes
console.log("data" , data)
}, [data])
```

A question for you: Why did you put your UI inside the state?